# Adding nofollow to all the post links in get_posts with pre_get_posts or WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, query

Can it be done with `pre_get_posts` in functions.php file to change the output by `get_posts` queries on blog/site.

I found nothing about adding html attribute to anchor tag here: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

Comment: Why not just add it manually: `<a rel="nofollow"...>` in your template/code? But `pre_get_posts` doesn't give you such functionality; the hook is for altering the `WP_Query` args and not modifying HTML.

Comment: `pre_get_posts` applies to all queries, including those from `get_posts()`. I don't see what `pre_get_posts` has to do with modifying post HTML though, since it's run _before_ (i.e. "pre") the posts are even retrieved from the database/